# How to use JS Flow types with Redux reducers and lodash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, redux, flowtype

I can type my actions, my initial state, and plain reducers, but when a reducer returns a slice of state that incorporates lodash, a third party utility library, Flow doesn't seem to detect it:

setup:

```
// @flow
import _ from 'lodash'
import constants from './constants';

type initialStateType = {
  authenticating: boolean,
  authenticated: boolean,
  goals: Array<?Object>,
  user: Object
}

type genericAction = {
  type: string,
  goals?: Array<?Object>,
  data?: Object | Array<mixed>,
  user?: Object,
  goalId?: ?number,
  status?: boolean,
}

export const initialState: initialStateType = {
  authenticating: false,
  authenticated: false,
  goals: [],
  user: {},
};
```

reducer cases that works with flow:

```
export function globalReducer(state: initialStateType = initialState, action: genericAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // Authentication
    case constants.AUTHENTICATING:
      return Object.assign({}, state,
        {
          authenticating: action.status,
        }
      );
...
    case constants.USER_EDITED:
    case constants.USER_FETCHED:
      return Object.assign({}, state,
        {
          user: action.user,
        }
    );
```

reducer cases that doesn't work with flow:

```
case constants.GOAL_CREATED:
      return Object.assign({}, state,
        {
          goals: _.concat(state.goals, action.data),
        }
      );
...
 case constants.GOAL_DELETED:
  return Object.assign({}, state,
    {
      goals: _.filter(state.goals, (value, index) => {
        return value.id !== action.goalId;
      }),
    }
  );
```

using Nuclide as my text editor with flow support built in, flow underlines the line, 'goals: _.concat(state.goals, action.data),' with a yellow message saying Type Coverage, Not covered by Flow.

How do I get proper flow coverage for these lines of code that use lodash?

[image: Type error from Flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install library definitions for lodash, otherwise Flow has no way of knowing what it does.

The easiest way to do this is via [`flow-typed`](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed). The instructions on that page should be enough to get you started. Basically, it is a tool that finds user-contributed library definitions for npm packages and puts them in your repository so Flow can use them.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is accepted, since there doesn't seem to be library definitions for lodash on the flow typed repository

Comment: https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/lodash_v4.x.x